# Setting Write path (MAC)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a Python 3 script that downloads a CSV file, but I can't specify the path.  The script saves the downloaded CSVs to the root user directory, but I'd like to specify the path to a different location.

Here is a snippet of my script:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as writer:
    writer.write(res)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the reason that script is writing the file to the users' home directories is because, one way or another, it is being run from there. If you have a `directoryname` variable, it could be as simple as:

```
import os

...

with open(os.path.join(directoryname, filename), 'wb') as writer:
    writer.write(res)
```

If the `filename` variable includes a leading path, eg something like:

```
path/to/filename.csv
```

then you'll have to deal with this by either:

- creating the containing directories (if they don't exist)
- removing the leading path (eg `os.path.basename(filename)`)

Also be aware that any directory that you provide can be either relative or absolute, so if it is relative, it would likely be evaluated relative to the user's home directory.

Comment: Thanks for checking out my first official question!  I'm actually running the script from a different directory.  The filename variable references the source file being downloaded;